# How to use standard URL in Backbone.Router?

Tags: backbone.js

According to the [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router) page:

> Until recently, hash fragments (#page) were used to provide these
>   permalinks, but with the arrival of the History API, **it's now
>   possible to use standard URLs (/page)**.

I tried to add this router rule:

```
routes: {
  'test': function() {
     alert('ok'); }
}
```

And called the `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: '/myroot/'})`. I have a link in my page as:

```
<a href="test">test me</a>
```

I intercepted the link's click event with:

```
$('a[href=test]').click(function(e) {
  router.navigate('test');
  e.preventDefault(); });
```

When I click on the link, a request is not made, which I believe the interception was succeeded. **But the event is not triggered.**

So, please help me understand how this `History API` works. Or point out where I have done wrong.

Comment: Problem solved. I should use `router.navigate('test', {trigger: true});`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to turn on pushState:

`Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});`

Your link is going to force a full refresh from your server and your server must respond with the content of that url.

You need to intercept that link's click and tell your router to navigate to the "test" route:

`myRouter.navigate("test");`

For more info on the HTML5 history api: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

for some intro level info on using pushState with Backbone:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-1-introducing-pushstate/

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-2-progressive-enhancement-with-backbone-js/

And a video of a presentation I gave that covers all of this:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/06/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-3-the-video/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Derick. I updated my code as you pointed out. But it still cannot work. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add {trigger: true}  to the navigate call to actually trigger routing events.

Answer (score 0):

To indicate that you'd like to use HTML5 **pushState** support in your application, use `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})`. If you'd like to use **pushState**, but have browsers that don't support it natively use full page refreshes instead, you can add `{hashChange: false}` to the options.

**PS!** If your application is not being served from the root url `/` of your domain, be sure to tell History where the root really is, as an option (otherwise the navigation won't work!):

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/public/search/"})
```